# Extracting specific text from a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Varchar field with information in it. As part of the information there is a Country which is listed as the first item of the string in all cases. What I want to do is run a Script that will extract from the field the first letter of the string up to and including the last letter before the first space in the string. I then having extracted it place it into a separate field in the same row

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQl 8, you can use REGEXP_SUBSTR

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('Canada Test JohnDoe', '^[A-Za-z]+') o from dual
```

for Mysql 5.5+

```
with cte as
(
   select 'Canada Test JohnDoe' x from dual
)
select SUBSTR(x, 1, LOCATE(' ', x)) o from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(col, ' ', 1) as country
```

If there is no space in the string, you will get the complete string. so this seems "safe".

Note:  This will not work for all countries.  Many have multiple names.  From "United States of America" and "United Kingdom" to the newest name addition, "North Macedonia"

Answer (score 0):

I think the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` can do the job.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 1) AS countryName
FROM tableName;

//SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delimiter,count)
```

you can find more information about this function [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)